# Unable to access Influxdb web UI. It shows 404 page not found error

Tags: influxdb, ubuntu-20.04, influxdb-python, influxdb-2

I have my influxdb working in server. When I try to open the influxdb UI using http://my_host:8086. I'm receiving 404 as response. What am I missing ? help me with this please.

Comment: Does it work when you try to curl localhost:8086 on the server running InfluxDB?

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.3, the web admin interface is no longer available in InfluxDB. The interface does not run on port 8083 and InfluxDB ignores the [admin] section in the configuration file if that section is present. Chronograf replaces the web admin interface with improved tooling for querying data, writing data, and database management. See Chronograf’s transition guide for more information.

[enter link description here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/tools/web_admin/)

Comment: The InfluxDB UI is indeed available in InfluxDB 2, please consider updating your answer accordingly

Comment: I haven't seen such a hint on the official website. Maybe you can use it in actual operation. Could you please show me the screenshot or the corresponding official website link

Comment: Afaik the exact port is only mentioned here: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.1/install/#set-up-influxdb-through-the-ui but the UI is mentioned quite often in the docs

Comment: Perhaps this is a divisive issue. The link I posted simply indicates that starting with InfluxDB 2, the old visualization interface is no longer supported, but a better visualization tool is available

Comment: https://www.influxdata.com/blog/influxdbs-checks-and-notifications-system/

Comment: From what I understood they simply integrated Kapacitor and Chronograf into Influx with v2 instead of delivering them as separate tools